# How to print list of nodes in available in xml file DOM4j library?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, dom4j

I have some xml file as below

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.shutterfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>CodingChallenges</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>CodingChallenges</name>
</project>
```

I want out put as printed below:

### output as:

modelVersion
groupId
artifactId
..
name
the pseudo code I tried:

```
File inputFile = new File(inputFilePath);
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
Document document = reader.read(inputFile);
System.out.println("Root element :" + document.getRootElement().getName());
Element classElement = document.getRootElement();
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes("/project");
for (Node node : nodes) {
    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + node.getName());
}
for (Iterator i = classElement.attributeIterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    Attribute attribute = (Attribute) i.next();
    System.out.println(attribute.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something simple as this:

```
    List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes("/project/*");
    for (Node node : nodes) {
        System.out.println(node.getName() + "=" + node.getText());
    }
```